# Firebase REST API Java(Not android). I got HTML Texts instead of my database value

Tags: java, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I was making my new REST API Java project with Firebase. I ran my code here:

```
URL url = new URL("https://restapi-example-java-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/get");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setDoInput(true);

conn.connect();
System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outResult.append(inputLine);
}

System.out.println(outResult);
```

However, what I could get was some kind of html which was about Google Login.
Response Message and Code of the connection was OK and 200;

My firebase rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from the REST API of the Realtime Database, the URL must end in `.json`. So:

```
new URL("https://restapi-example-java-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/get.json");
                                                                                          //
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting started with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start):

> We can use any Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint. **All we need to do is append `.json` to the end of the URL** and send a request from our favorite HTTPS client.